# SwiftUI: Content has padding

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created an optional Scrollview which means that I disable the scrolling behaviour if the needed size of the content fits into the provides space for the ScrollView. It works well on iPhone11 but has a strange effect on iPhone SE. Here a padding appears between the outer Scrollview and the content like you can see on the image. This has the effect that different page elements are not aligned.

[image]

Do you see where the green part is coming from? Why isn't the red part using all available space? "Lorem ipsum..." should be left aligned with "This is..."

```
struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}

struct OptionalScrollView: View {
    @State private var fitInScreen = true
    @State private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    let text: Text
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {          // container to calculate total height
                    self.text.background(Color.red)
                }.background(Color.yellow)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    // calculate height by consumed background and store in
                    // view preference
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                })
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) {
                self.fitInScreen = $0 < geo.size.height
                self.contentHeight = $0
            }
            .disabled(self.fitInScreen)
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: self.contentHeight)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: No green sides with Xcode 12 / iPhone SE 2 simulator.

Comment: depends on the text I found out. Please use a longer text and remove some chars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as expected; Text is self-tight to consumed space. `VStack` is tight to intrinsic content, ie. Text. If you want to expand `Text` (or `VStack`, or both) to available width, do this explicitly

*default*

[image: demo]

*with frame*

[image: demo2]

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {          // container to calculate total height
        self.text
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)     // << here !!
            .background(Color.red)
    }.background(Color.yellow)
```