# LazyVGrid with Text() affects spacing when content is empty

Tags: ios, swiftui, spacing, lazyvgrid

Total newbie, in Swift and SwiftUI but I couldn't find a straightforward answer hence, asking here.

I have a  `LazyVGrid` that contains a `ForEach` that renders `RoundedRectangle` that contains `Text`. The grid wraps the rectangles correctly and adds the spacing between the rows. However, when tapping on a rectangle, I remove the contained `Text` and when I do this for all items in a row, the items shift momentarily.

I get that there is some inner padding/margin/etc. going coming from within `Text` but this is not visible in the content view preview. I can of course, easily fix it by having an empty `Text`, but this doesn't feel right.

Can someone explain why this is happening and any ideas on how to properly fix it? -- Thanks

**related code:**

```swift
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 65))]) {
    ForEach(emojis[0..<emojiCount], id: \.self) { emoji in
        CardView(content: emoji).aspectRatio(3/4, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}

//----

struct CardView: View {
    var content: String
    @State var isFaceUp = true
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            
            if isFaceUp {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
                Text(content).font(.largeTitle)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what is happening here either, but setting `maxHeight` to infinity works:

```
Text(content).font(.largeTitle).frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
```

`ZStack` would normally try to fit its contents, and the `Text` has some mysterious bottom padding, requiring the `ZStack` to expand. I suspect that this works by telling the `Text` to fit the `ZStack`, rather than the other way round.

The solution looks very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63174415/5133585), where a `Text` has undesired padding because its frame is squeezed to fit the content, rather than the container.

Another solution is to use an `overlay`:

```
shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3).overlay {
    Text(content).font(.largeTitle)
}
```

This works because the parent view's frame is not affected by its overlays, and so the existence/absence of an overlay does not change the parent view's frame.